# Phaser.js + Electron Framework. Почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, electron, phaser-framework

Пытаюсь подключить фреймворк phaser.js к electron, для создания desktop-игры на html5. Не работает код из файла renderer.js. Phaser в консоли показывает, что его инициализация была успешна.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>require('./phaser/v3/src/phaser.js')</script>
    <script>require('./renderer.js')</script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

renderer.js

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
    game.load.image('Conquest', 'assets/Conquest.png');
}

function create() {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Conquest');
}

function update() {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Conquest');
    console.log('update');
}
```

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const Menu = electron.Menu
const {dialog} = require('electron')
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }
  }))

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  mainWindow.setMenu(null)
  mainWindow.maximize()

}

app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Создания окна(canvas) и отрисовка там спрайта.

Answer (score 1):

Вы подключаете исходники библиотеки. Её надо собрать, прежде чем использовать. В папке `dist` проекта лежит то, что вам надо. В вашем случае, это

```html
<script>require('./phaser/v3/dist/phaser.js')</script>
```

И не рекомендую v3. Она слишком сырая даже для альфы. Об этом Richard Davey писал в рассылке.